# Word count in go

Tags: go

i want to write a program that given a file returns the frequencies of word occurencies in order from the most frequent to the less frequent, here is the code I wrote:

```
var counts = make(map[string]float64)
var countTotal float64

file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
for scanner.Scan() {
    counts[scanner.Text()] += 1.0
    countTotal += 1.0
}

var words = make([]string, 0, len(counts))
for word := range counts {
    words = append(words, word)
}
sort.SliceStable(words, func(i, j int) bool {
    return counts[words[i]] < counts[words[j]]
})

for _, word := range words {
    fmt.Println(word, ": ", counts[word]/countTotal)
}
```

What i obtained is the word frequencies but in the inverse order, from the less frequent to the more frequent, can someone help to let me know why my program is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You use a `less()` function when sorting that says a word is less (comes earlier in the list) if its count is less. If you want to list words with higher counts first, negate the relation: `return counts[words[i]] > counts[words[j]]`. Also there's no need to stable-sort it: you populate the slice by iterating over the map, which order is random.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `less()` function in the `sort.SliceStable()`

Now what you have there is the sorting in the ascending order.
To change that, simply specify the `less()` function as

```
return counts[words[i]] > counts[words[j]]
```